# Decryp error not consistent on different strings

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to decrypt data using a cypher and it does encrypt fine, however I can't decrypt from it in certain cases, always getting error:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.'
```

I'm really not sure why it's not decrypting.
Here is my source code to encrypt and decrypt:

```
private static byte[] key = new byte[8] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    private static byte[] iv = new byte[8] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    public static string Crypt(this string text)
    {
        SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = DES.Create();
        ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
        byte[] inputbuffer = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] outputBuffer = transform.TransformFinalBlock(inputbuffer, 0, inputbuffer.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBuffer);
    }

    public static string Decrypt(this string text)
    {
        SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = DES.Create();
        ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
        byte[] inputbuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
        byte[] outputBuffer = transform.TransformFinalBlock(inputbuffer, 0, inputbuffer.Length);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(outputBuffer);
    }
```

I've tried to find the answer however I'm not sure if it's a flaw on the decrypting method, because it does work most of the times, but on some cases this error comes up. I can't figure out why the error comes up, I've compared with other longer strings I've encrypted that decrypt just fine.Sometimes it crashes with 71 characters but it works fine with another string of 282 characters.
I've removed special characters not supported by base64 and left only  "/" as it is supported.

EDIT:
as an example, this string works correctly With 258 characters:

Original:

```
"The room has three rooms, two of them are rooms with 2 double beds, a large wardrobe, bathroom in each room, the third room, is a living room, where there is a breakfast room, large refrigerator, television, telephone, microwave, coffee maker, plus a terrace"
```

Encypted string:

```
"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"
```

While this other string does not decrypt(with just 79 characters):

Original:

```
Name:Dance classes/Description:Dance classes with Joan the dancer/Picture:IMAGE
```

Encrypted:

```
ha3P4ZB+q3dCn2HLwWUTH/vJ3IEgKAW9Ha/33Co9bgUuPym+cgSs6dndhecKdOXRZVjw4hx/qKxpMGMXVH+X70jZogA/Ef08AGzV/GTnz4S8UM0q2+VK6epL7P0D0Mz2b+NrD86Fu7FGvaHrlhiOHwT5h87EmlOkn1jHhKKdf+khRDbYyvECrKfSa5SZg0OAHv3Z6nuO
```

Comment: To provide us with a [mcve] please provide a sample string which fails and any steps you take to "help" the process.

Comment: Thanks, I added an example on the post

Comment: The `does not decrypt` string makes the round trip fine for me (using instance methods).  A) You ought read up on `IDisposable` because your app is leaking, B) In spite of the error message, the problem is not in the length of the string - the decryptor is working with encrypted, *encoded* data after all.  C) the IV ought to be random bytes and typically the key would come from the user. D) no need to filter out characters for any reason.  /fin

Comment: You should also read the Wikipedia page on DES. That algorithm shouldn't be used except for historical purposes. It was obsolete a decade or two ago.